# Best resource for Scraping multiple tables with unchanging URL using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape tables on web pages that have next links, but when you click these next buttons the URL won't change. What are the best/easiest resources to learn scraping with python (BeautifulSoup, Requests) to scrape these kinds of tables?

For example how do I scrape the tables on [this page from Boone County Sheriff's Department](https://report.boonecountymo.org/mrcjava/servlet/SH01_MP.I00290s).

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use Selenium instead of requests. That way you can have the power of interacting with javascript based actions.

Code:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

chromeOptions = Options()
chromeOptions.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chromeOptions)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
driver.get('https://report.boonecountymo.org/mrcjava/servlet/SH01_MP.I00290s')

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
page_numbers = int(str(soup.find('a', string=re.compile('Page 1 of '), href='#').text).split('Page 1 of ')[1])
print(page_numbers)

tables = []

for page in range(1, page_numbers + 1):
    if page == 1:
        table = soup.find('tbody', id='mrc_main_table')
        #print(table)
        tables.append(table)
    else:
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//a[@class="page-button"][@data-pagetype="btn_next"]')))
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="page-button"][@data-pagetype="btn_next"]').click()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
        table = soup.find('tbody', id='mrc_main_table')
        #print(table)
        tables.append(table)

print(tables)
```

Output:

```
5
[<tbody class="stripe" id="mrc_main_table">
<!-- -->
<tr class="odd">
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Last Name">AARON</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="First Name">KEVIN</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Middle Name">PHILLIP</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Sex">M</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Race">B</td>
<td class="one td_right" data-th="Age">23</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="City">COLUMBIA</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="State">MO</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="">
<a class="_lookup btn btn-primary" height="600" href="SH01_MP.I00500s?PERKEP=66343&amp;hover_redir=&amp;height=600&amp;width=950" linkedtype="I" mrc="returndata" target="_lookup" width="860"><i class="fa fa-large fa-fw fa-list-alt"> </i>Details</a>
</td>
</tr>
<!-- -->
<tr class="even">
<td class="two td_left" data-th="Last Name">ADAM</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="First Name">OMER</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="Middle Name">SIRAJ</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="Sex">M</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="Race">B</td>
<td class="two td_right" data-th="Age">29</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="City">COLUMBIA</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="State">MO</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="">
<a class="_lookup btn btn-primary" height="600" href="SH01_MP.I00500s?PERKEP=77695&amp;hover_redir=&amp;height=600&amp;width=950" linkedtype="I" mrc="returndata" target="_lookup" width="860"><i class="fa fa-large fa-fw fa-list-alt"> </i>Details</a>
</td>
</tr>
<!-- -->
<tr class="odd">
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Last Name">AKERS</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="First Name">BRANDEN</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Middle Name">MICHAEL</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Sex">M</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Race">W</td>
<td class="one td_right" data-th="Age">32</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="City">MOKANE</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="State">MO</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="">
<a class="_lookup btn btn-primary" height="600" href="SH01_MP.I00500s?PERKEP=51443&amp;hover_redir=&amp;height=600&amp;width=950" linkedtype="I" mrc="returndata" target="_lookup" width="860"><i class="fa fa-large fa-fw fa-list-alt"> </i>Details</a>
</td>
</tr>
<!-- -->
<tr class="even">
<td class="two td_left" data-th="Last Name">AKERS</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="First Name">SYDNEY</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="Middle Name">RAE</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="Sex">F</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="Race">W</td>
<td class="two td_right" data-th="Age">20</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="City">COLUMBIA</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="State">MO</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="">
<a class="_lookup btn btn-primary" height="600" href="SH01_MP.I00500s?PERKEP=76028&amp;hover_redir=&amp;height=600&amp;width=950" linkedtype="I" mrc="returndata" target="_lookup" width="860"><i class="fa fa-large fa-fw fa-list-alt"> </i>Details</a>
</td>
</tr>
<!-- -->
<tr class="odd">
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Last Name">ALLEN</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="First Name">WILLIAM</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Middle Name">LAMAR</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Sex">M</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Race">B</td>
<td class="one td_right" data-th="Age">55</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="City">COLUMBIA</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="State">MO</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="">
<a class="_lookup btn btn-primary" height="600" href="SH01_MP.I00500s?PERKEP=19022&amp;hover_redir=&amp;height=600&amp;width=950" linkedtype="I" mrc="returndata" target="_lookup" width="860"><i class="fa fa-large fa-fw fa-list-alt"> </i>Details</a>
</td>
</tr>
<!-- -->
<tr class="even">
<td class="two td_left" data-th="Last Name">ALVARADO</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="First Name">JACOVO</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="Middle Name"> </td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="Sex">M</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="Race">H</td>
<td class="two td_right" data-th="Age">34</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="City">COLUMBIA</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="State">MO</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="">
<a class="_lookup btn btn-primary" height="600" href="SH01_MP.I00500s?PERKEP=79782&amp;hover_redir=&amp;height=600&amp;width=950" linkedtype="I" mrc="returndata" target="_lookup" width="860"><i class="fa fa-large fa-fw fa-list-alt"> </i>Details</a>
</td>
</tr>
<!-- -->
<tr class="odd">
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Last Name">ANDERSON</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="First Name">RICHARD</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Middle Name">KENNETH</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Sex">M</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Race">B</td>
<td class="one td_right" data-th="Age">24</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="City">COLUMBIA</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="State">MO</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="">
<a class="_lookup btn btn-primary" height="600" href="SH01_MP.I00500s?PERKEP=66544&amp;hover_redir=&amp;height=600&amp;width=950" linkedtype="I" mrc="returndata" target="_lookup" width="860"><i class="fa fa-large fa-fw fa-list-alt"> </i>Details</a>
</td>
</tr>
<!-- -->
<tr class="even">
<td class="two td_left" data-th="Last Name">AVALOS-AVALOS</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="First Name">JOSE</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="Middle Name"> </td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="Sex">M</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="Race">H</td>
<td class="two td_right" data-th="Age">19</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="City">ST.ANN</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="State">MO</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="">
<a class="_lookup btn btn-primary" height="600" href="SH01_MP.I00500s?PERKEP=78424&amp;hover_redir=&amp;height=600&amp;width=950" linkedtype="I" mrc="returndata" target="_lookup" width="860"><i class="fa fa-large fa-fw fa-list-alt"> </i>Details</a>
</td>
</tr>
<!-- -->
<tr class="odd">
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Last Name">AVILES</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="First Name">LUCIANO</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Middle Name">ESPINOZA</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Sex">M</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Race">H</td>
<td class="one td_right" data-th="Age">21</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="City">COLUMBIA</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="State">MO</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="">
<a class="_lookup btn btn-primary" height="600" href="SH01_MP.I00500s?PERKEP=79931&amp;hover_redir=&amp;height=600&amp;width=950" linkedtype="I" mrc="returndata" target="_lookup" width="860"><i class="fa fa-large fa-fw fa-list-alt"> </i>Details</a>
</td>
</tr>
<!-- -->
<tr class="even">
<td class="two td_left" data-th="Last Name">BAILEY</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="First Name">JAMES</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="Middle Name">LEROY</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="Sex">M</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="Race">W</td>
<td class="two td_right" data-th="Age">50</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="City">COLUMBIA</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="State">MO</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="">
<a class="_lookup btn btn-primary" height="600" href="SH01_MP.I00500s?PERKEP=18934&amp;hover_redir=&amp;height=600&amp;width=950" linkedtype="I" mrc="returndata" target="_lookup" width="860"><i class="fa fa-large fa-fw fa-list-alt"> </i>Details</a>
</td>
</tr>
<!-- -->
<tr class="odd">
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Last Name">BARNEY</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="First Name">FELSON</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Middle Name">DEVONE</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Sex">M</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Race">B</td>
<td class="one td_right" data-th="Age">40</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="City">COLUMBIA</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="State">MO</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="">
<a class="_lookup btn btn-primary" height="600" href="SH01_MP.I00500s?PERKEP=4285&amp;hover_redir=&amp;height=600&amp;width=950" linkedtype="I" mrc="returndata" target="_lookup" width="860"><i class="fa fa-large fa-fw fa-list-alt"> </i>Details</a>
</td>
</tr>
<!-- -->
<tr class="even">
<td class="two td_left" data-th="Last Name">BARTON</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="First Name">JAMES</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="Middle Name">EDWARD</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="Sex">M</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="Race">W</td>
<td class="two td_right" data-th="Age">63</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="City">COLUMBIA</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="State">MO</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="">
<a class="_lookup btn btn-primary" height="600" href="SH01_MP.I00500s?PERKEP=76341&amp;hover_redir=&amp;height=600&amp;width=950" linkedtype="I" mrc="returndata" target="_lookup" width="860"><i class="fa fa-large fa-fw fa-list-alt"> </i>Details</a>
</td>
</tr>
<!-- -->
<tr class="odd">
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Last Name">BELL</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="First Name">COLIN</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Middle Name">KEITH</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Sex">M</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Race">W</td>
<td class="one td_right" data-th="Age">35</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="City">HALLSVILLE</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="State">MO</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="">
<a class="_lookup btn btn-primary" height="600" href="SH01_MP.I00500s?PERKEP=33000&amp;hover_redir=&amp;height=600&amp;width=950" linkedtype="I" mrc="returndata" target="_lookup" width="860"><i class="fa fa-large fa-fw fa-list-alt"> </i>Details</a>
</td>
</tr>
<!-- -->
<tr class="even">
<td class="two td_left" data-th="Last Name">BENEDETTI</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="First Name">FRANK</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="Middle Name">DOMINICK</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="Sex">M</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="Race">W</td>
<td class="two td_right" data-th="Age">29</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="City">COLUMBIA</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="State">MO</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="">
<a class="_lookup btn btn-primary" height="600" href="SH01_MP.I00500s?PERKEP=79913&amp;hover_redir=&amp;height=600&amp;width=950" linkedtype="I" mrc="returndata" target="_lookup" width="860"><i class="fa fa-large fa-fw fa-list-alt"> </i>Details</a>
</td>
</tr>
<!-- -->
<tr class="odd">
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Last Name">BENNETT</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="First Name">ROBERT</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Middle Name">DAVID</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Sex">M</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Race">B</td>
<td class="one td_right" data-th="Age">39</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="City">COLUMBIA</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="State">MO</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="">
<a class="_lookup btn btn-primary" height="600" href="SH01_MP.I00500s?PERKEP=33666&amp;hover_redir=&amp;height=600&amp;width=950" linkedtype="I" mrc="returndata" target="_lookup" width="860"><i class="fa fa-large fa-fw fa-list-alt"> </i>Details</a>
</td>
</tr>
<!-- -->
<tr class="even">
<td class="two td_left" data-th="Last Name">BERARDI</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="First Name">DEBORAH</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="Middle Name">EVA</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="Sex">F</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="Race">W</td>
<td class="two td_right" data-th="Age">56</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="City">COLUMBIA</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="State">MO</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="">
<a class="_lookup btn btn-primary" height="600" href="SH01_MP.I00500s?PERKEP=78005&amp;hover_redir=&amp;height=600&amp;width=950" linkedtype="I" mrc="returndata" target="_lookup" width="860"><i class="fa fa-large fa-fw fa-list-alt"> </i>Details</a>
</td>
</tr>
<!-- -->
<tr class="odd">
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Last Name">BLAIR</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="First Name">RYAN</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Middle Name">WADE</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Sex">M</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Race">W</td>
<td class="one td_right" data-th="Age">26</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="City">MEXICO</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="State">MO</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="">
<a class="_lookup btn btn-primary" height="600" href="SH01_MP.I00500s?PERKEP=73590&amp;hover_redir=&amp;height=600&amp;width=950" linkedtype="I" mrc="returndata" target="_lookup" width="860"><i class="fa fa-large fa-fw fa-list-alt"> </i>Details</a>
</td>
</tr>
<!-- -->
<tr class="even">
<td class="two td_left" data-th="Last Name">BOND</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="First Name">SOPHIA</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="Middle Name">LYNN</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="Sex">F</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="Race">W</td>
<td class="two td_right" data-th="Age">23</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="City">COLUMBIA</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="State">MO</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="">
<a class="_lookup btn btn-primary" height="600" href="SH01_MP.I00500s?PERKEP=67252&amp;hover_redir=&amp;height=600&amp;width=950" linkedtype="I" mrc="returndata" target="_lookup" width="860"><i class="fa fa-large fa-fw fa-list-alt"> </i>Details</a>
</td>
</tr>
<!-- -->
<tr class="odd">
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Last Name">BOONE</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="First Name">NIKKI</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Middle Name">MARIE</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Sex">F</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Race">W</td>
<td class="one td_right" data-th="Age">33</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="City">COLUMBIALE</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="State">MO</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="">
<a class="_lookup btn btn-primary" height="600" href="SH01_MP.I00500s?PERKEP=39306&amp;hover_redir=&amp;height=600&amp;width=950" linkedtype="I" mrc="returndata" target="_lookup" width="860"><i class="fa fa-large fa-fw fa-list-alt"> </i>Details</a>
</td>
</tr>
<!-- -->
<tr class="even">
<td class="two td_left" data-th="Last Name">BOSS</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="First Name">JAFARI</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="Middle Name">RASHIDI</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="Sex">M</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="Race">B</td>
<td class="two td_right" data-th="Age">34</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="City">COLUMBIA</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="State">MO</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="">
<a class="_lookup btn btn-primary" height="600" href="SH01_MP.I00500s?PERKEP=60725&amp;hover_redir=&amp;height=600&amp;width=950" linkedtype="I" mrc="returndata" target="_lookup" width="860"><i class="fa fa-large fa-fw fa-list-alt"> </i>Details</a>
</td>
</tr>
<!-- -->
<tr class="odd">
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Last Name">BOYDSTON</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="First Name">LAVERNE</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Middle Name">KEHAULANI</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Sex">F</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Race">A</td>
<td class="one td_right" data-th="Age">59</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="City">MOBERLY</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="State">MO</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="">
<a class="_lookup btn btn-primary" height="600" href="SH01_MP.I00500s?PERKEP=79939&amp;hover_redir=&amp;height=600&amp;width=950" linkedtype="I" mrc="returndata" target="_lookup" width="860"><i class="fa fa-large fa-fw fa-list-alt"> </i>Details</a>
</td>
</tr>
<!-- -->
<tr class="even">
<td class="two td_left" data-th="Last Name">BRILL</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="First Name">BRANDON</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="Middle Name">NICHOLAS</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="Sex">M</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="Race">W</td>
<td class="two td_right" data-th="Age">26</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="City">CLARK</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="State">MO</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="">
<a class="_lookup btn btn-primary" height="600" href="SH01_MP.I00500s?PERKEP=60089&amp;hover_redir=&amp;height=600&amp;width=950" linkedtype="I" mrc="returndata" target="_lookup" width="860"><i class="fa fa-large fa-fw fa-list-alt"> </i>Details</a>
</td>
</tr>
<!-- -->
<tr class="odd">
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Last Name">BROWN</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="First Name">THYRUS</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Middle Name">MONTEZ</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Sex">M</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Race">B</td>
<td class="one td_right" data-th="Age">48</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="City">COLUMBIA</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="State">MO</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="">
<a class="_lookup btn btn-primary" height="600" href="SH01_MP.I00500s?PERKEP=45497&amp;hover_redir=&amp;height=600&amp;width=950" linkedtype="I" mrc="returndata" target="_lookup" width="860"><i class="fa fa-large fa-fw fa-list-alt"> </i>Details</a>
</td>
</tr>
<!-- -->
<tr class="even">
<td class="two td_left" data-th="Last Name">BRYANT</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="First Name">CHESTER</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="Middle Name">LEROY</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="Sex">M</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="Race">B</td>
<td class="two td_right" data-th="Age">53</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="City">COLUMBIA</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="State">MO</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="">
<a class="_lookup btn btn-primary" height="600" href="SH01_MP.I00500s?PERKEP=10513&amp;hover_redir=&amp;height=600&amp;width=950" linkedtype="I" mrc="returndata" target="_lookup" width="860"><i class="fa fa-large fa-fw fa-list-alt"> </i>Details</a>
</td>
</tr>
................
ETC...
................

<!-- -->
<tr class="odd">
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Last Name">WILLIAMS</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="First Name">SYLVESTER</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Middle Name">EARL</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Sex">M</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Race">B</td>
<td class="one td_right" data-th="Age">50</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="City">COLUMBIA</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="State">MO</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="">
<a class="_lookup btn btn-primary" height="600" href="SH01_MP.I00500s?PERKEP=8656&amp;hover_redir=&amp;height=600&amp;width=950" linkedtype="I" mrc="returndata" target="_lookup" width="860"><i class="fa fa-large fa-fw fa-list-alt"> </i>Details</a>
</td>
</tr>
<!-- -->
<tr class="even">
<td class="two td_left" data-th="Last Name">WINTER</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="First Name">PAIGE</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="Middle Name">LYNN</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="Sex">F</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="Race">W</td>
<td class="two td_right" data-th="Age">20</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="City">COLUMBIA</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="State">MO</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="">
<a class="_lookup btn btn-primary" height="600" href="SH01_MP.I00500s?PERKEP=75775&amp;hover_redir=&amp;height=600&amp;width=950" linkedtype="I" mrc="returndata" target="_lookup" width="860"><i class="fa fa-large fa-fw fa-list-alt"> </i>Details</a>
</td>
</tr>
<!-- -->
<tr class="odd">
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Last Name">WISLEY</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="First Name">JORDAN</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Middle Name">MONTEZ</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Sex">M</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Race">B</td>
<td class="one td_right" data-th="Age">27</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="City">COLUMBIA</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="State">MO</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="">
<a class="_lookup btn btn-primary" height="600" href="SH01_MP.I00500s?PERKEP=58487&amp;hover_redir=&amp;height=600&amp;width=950" linkedtype="I" mrc="returndata" target="_lookup" width="860"><i class="fa fa-large fa-fw fa-list-alt"> </i>Details</a>
</td>
</tr>
<!-- -->
<tr class="even">
<td class="two td_left" data-th="Last Name">WOODS</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="First Name">DANIEL</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="Middle Name">SCOTT</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="Sex">M</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="Race">W</td>
<td class="two td_right" data-th="Age">33</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="City">COLUMBIA</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="State">MO</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="">
<a class="_lookup btn btn-primary" height="600" href="SH01_MP.I00500s?PERKEP=39227&amp;hover_redir=&amp;height=600&amp;width=950" linkedtype="I" mrc="returndata" target="_lookup" width="860"><i class="fa fa-large fa-fw fa-list-alt"> </i>Details</a>
</td>
</tr>
<!-- -->
<tr class="odd">
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Last Name">WOODWARD</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="First Name">ELAINIA</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Middle Name">MARGURITE</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Sex">F</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Race">B</td>
<td class="one td_right" data-th="Age">19</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="City">TOPEKA</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="State">KS</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="">
<a class="_lookup btn btn-primary" height="600" href="SH01_MP.I00500s?PERKEP=79008&amp;hover_redir=&amp;height=600&amp;width=950" linkedtype="I" mrc="returndata" target="_lookup" width="860"><i class="fa fa-large fa-fw fa-list-alt"> </i>Details</a>
</td>
</tr>
<!-- -->
<tr class="even">
<td class="two td_left" data-th="Last Name">WYATT</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="First Name">CHASE</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="Middle Name">ROY</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="Sex">M</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="Race">W</td>
<td class="two td_right" data-th="Age">31</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="City">CENTRALIA</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="State">MO</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="">
<a class="_lookup btn btn-primary" height="600" href="SH01_MP.I00500s?PERKEP=59360&amp;hover_redir=&amp;height=600&amp;width=950" linkedtype="I" mrc="returndata" target="_lookup" width="860"><i class="fa fa-large fa-fw fa-list-alt"> </i>Details</a>
</td>
</tr>
<!-- -->
<tr class="odd">
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Last Name">YEARWOOD</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="First Name">JAMES</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Middle Name">CHRISTIAN</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Sex">M</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Race">B</td>
<td class="one td_right" data-th="Age">19</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="City">COLUMBIA</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="State">MO</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="">
<a class="_lookup btn btn-primary" height="600" href="SH01_MP.I00500s?PERKEP=77805&amp;hover_redir=&amp;height=600&amp;width=950" linkedtype="I" mrc="returndata" target="_lookup" width="860"><i class="fa fa-large fa-fw fa-list-alt"> </i>Details</a>
</td>
</tr>
<!-- -->
<tr class="even">
<td class="two td_left" data-th="Last Name">ZARHOUNI</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="First Name">DRISS</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="Middle Name">BURCH</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="Sex">M</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="Race">H</td>
<td class="two td_right" data-th="Age">53</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="City">COLUMBIA</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="State">MO</td>
<td class="two td_left" data-th="">
<a class="_lookup btn btn-primary" height="600" href="SH01_MP.I00500s?PERKEP=33263&amp;hover_redir=&amp;height=600&amp;width=950" linkedtype="I" mrc="returndata" target="_lookup" width="860"><i class="fa fa-large fa-fw fa-list-alt"> </i>Details</a>
</td>
</tr>
<!-- -->
<tr class="odd">
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Last Name">ZWICKY</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="First Name">CARRIE</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Middle Name">ANN</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Sex">F</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="Race">W</td>
<td class="one td_right" data-th="Age">45</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="City">GALESBURG</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="State">IL</td>
<td class="one td_left" data-th="">
<a class="_lookup btn btn-primary" height="600" href="SH01_MP.I00500s?PERKEP=79930&amp;hover_redir=&amp;height=600&amp;width=950" linkedtype="I" mrc="returndata" target="_lookup" width="860"><i class="fa fa-large fa-fw fa-list-alt"> </i>Details</a>
</td>
</tr>
<!-- -->
<tr class="tr-paging">
<th class="th_left paging_row bottomPaging" colspan="93">  Detainee Count: 235
                            <div class="pagination pagination-right fixed-pagination" style="margin-left: 2em;">
<ul>
<li>
<a class="page-button" data-pagetype="btn_top" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-left fa-large"> </i></a>
</li>
<li>
<a class="page-button" data-pagetype="btn_prev" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fa fa-angle-left fa-large"> </i></a>
</li>
<li class="disabled">
<a href="#">Page 5 of 5</a>
</li>
<li>
<a class="" data-pagetype="btn_next" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-large"> </i></a>
</li>
<li>
<a class="" data-pagetype="btn_btmm" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right fa-large"> </i></a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</th>
</tr>
</tbody>]
```

Comment: The script does parse all the pages dynamically depending on how many pages there are in the URL. The output I provided has missing results on purpose,  because there is a limit on how many characters I can use in an answer.